# Reproducibility in the groupdata2 R package when creating data folds

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I'm trying to create data folds for cross validation in a matched case-control study design. The goal is to account for the matching strata in the CV.

Presumably, this can be done in R using the groupdata2 package. However, for some reasons I am not able to get reproducible results, despite setting the seed.

I'm providing a toy example below, which I partly borrowed from the vignette for the package.

Thank you!

```
    # Attach some packages
library(groupdata2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr) # kable()
library(broom) #tidy()


# Create data frame
df <- data.frame("participant" = factor(as.integer(
  rep(c('1','2', '3', '4', '5', 
        '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'), 3))),
  "age" = rep(c(20,23,27,21,32,31,43,21,34,32), 3),
  "diagnosis" = factor(rep(c('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 
                             'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'), 3)),
  "score" = c(10,24,15,35,24,14,11,16,33,29,  # for 1st session
              24,40,30,50,54,25,35,32,53,55,  # for 2nd session
              45,67,40,78,62,30,41,44,66,81)) # for 3rd session

# Order by participant
df <- df %>% arrange(participant)

# Remove index
rownames(df) <- NULL

# Add session info
df$session <- as.integer(rep(c('1','2', '3'), 10))

# Show the data frame
kable(df, align = 'c')

set.seed(1) # For reproducibility?
df <- fold(df, k = 4, handle_existing_fold_cols = "keep") #first fold set
set.seed(1) # For reproducibility?
df <- fold(df, k = 4, handle_existing_fold_cols = "keep") #second fold set - should be the same as first one since using the same seed

# Show the data frame
kable(df, align = 'c')

 participant | age | diagnosis | score | session | .folds_1 | .folds_2 |
|:-----------:|:---:|:---------:|:-----:|:-------:|:--------:|:--------:|
|      1      | 20  |     a     |  24   |    2    |    1     |    1     |
|      1      | 20  |     a     |  45   |    3    |    1     |    3     |
|      2      | 23  |     b     |  24   |    1    |    1     |    4     |
|      2      | 23  |     b     |  40   |    2    |    1     |    2     |
|      6      | 31  |     a     |  25   |    2    |    1     |    3     |
|      9      | 34  |     b     |  33   |    1    |    1     |    2     |
|     10      | 32  |     b     |  29   |    1    |    1     |    4     |
|      3      | 27  |     a     |  15   |    1    |    2     |    3     |
|      3      | 27  |     a     |  30   |    2    |    2     |    1     |
|      4      | 21  |     b     |  78   |    3    |    2     |    2     |
|      6      | 31  |     a     |  14   |    1    |    2     |    4     |
|      7      | 43  |     a     |  11   |    1    |    2     |    1     |
|      7      | 43  |     a     |  35   |    2    |    2     |    2     |
|      7      | 43  |     a     |  41   |    3    |    2     |    3     |
|      8      | 21  |     a     |  44   |    3    |    2     |    4     |
|      3      | 27  |     a     |  40   |    3    |    3     |    4     |
|      4      | 21  |     b     |  35   |    1    |    3     |    4     |
|      5      | 32  |     b     |  54   |    2    |    3     |    2     |
|      6      | 31  |     a     |  30   |    3    |    3     |    2     |
|      8      | 21  |     a     |  16   |    1    |    3     |    1     |
|      9      | 34  |     b     |  53   |    2    |    3     |    3     |
|     10      | 32  |     b     |  81   |    3    |    3     |    3     |
|      1      | 20  |     a     |  10   |    1    |    4     |    3     |
|      2      | 23  |     b     |  67   |    3    |    4     |    1     |
|      4      | 21  |     b     |  50   |    2    |    4     |    4     |
|      5      | 32  |     b     |  24   |    1    |    4     |    4     |
|      5      | 32  |     b     |  62   |    3    |    4     |    3     |
|      8      | 21  |     a     |  32   |    2    |    4     |    1     |
|      9      | 34  |     b     |  66   |    3    |    4     |    2     |
|     10      | 32  |     b     |  55   |    2    |    4     |    2     |
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature. These below codes give the same results. The fold() was designed to make sure it always generates a different fold column given an existing fold column.

```
set.seed(1) 
df1 <- fold(df, k = 4, handle_existing_fold_cols = "keep") 
set.seed(1) 
df2 <- fold(df1[-6], k = 4, handle_existing_fold_cols = "keep")
cbind(df1[6],df2[6])
```